# Use godownloader.sh but couldn't find the binary file in /usr/local/bin

Tags: shell, go, command-line-interface

I use `goreleaser` to publish my release and `godownloader` to create the shell script for installation.

I run the command on my Mac:

```bash
sudo /bin/sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/myusername/myapp/main/godownloader.sh)" -- -b /usr/local/bin
```

I got

```
myusername/myapp info checking GitHub for latest tag 
myusername/myapp info found version: 0.1.0 for v0.1.0/darwin/arm64
```

I've checked my releases; it has no problems.

But when I checked the `/usr/local/bin` folder, the binary file wasn't there. My shell couldnt find the command either. I also checked the time of last modification, confirmed the binary file wasn't installed in `bin`.

My `godownloader.sh` is default generated, it's from [godownloader](https://github.com/kamilsk/godownloader/tree/homebrew).

I want to know what went wrong and how to fix 'can't find the command (my binary file name)' in the terminal.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edit. You are welcome to post your answer as an actual answer, but the question should remain strictly a question. (Your text is available from the [revision history.)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77549971/revisions)

Comment: Thank you for the info, i ve posted the answer

Comment: For what it's worth, the script is not a Bash script if you use `sh` to run it. See also [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

Comment: I always confuse these two, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem, it's because of the `godownloader.sh`, check your download URL, which is `TARBALL_URL`. I also changed `fi install "${srcdir}/${binexe}" "${BINDIR}/${BINARY}"` to `fi install "${srcdir}/${NAME}" "${BINDIR}/${BINARY}"`, remove the line of `hash_sha256_verify "${tmpdir}/${TARBALL}" "${tmpdir}/${CHECKSUM}"` and the part of  `&& untar "${TARBALL}"`, and now everything works fine. I think it's because my releases are not tar - check your releases and then modify corresponding lines.